# Aiogram error iogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit

Tags: python, aiogram

в боте на aiogram-dialog есть визард для создания заявки, где есть поле "описание". Если тип контента описания text, document, video, audio, photo, то все отрабатывает корректно. Но если тип описания voice (голосовое), то при нажатии любой кнопки в превью-окне бот падает в ошибку, которая в заголовке.

Ссылка на гитхаб на бота:

https://github.com/oooazimut/SupportBot/tree/operator

Диалог создания заявки в dialogs/task.